# Cannot resolve method 'super(int, java.lang.String,com.android.volley.Response.Listener<java.lang.String>,null)'

Tags: android, database, android-studio

So, I have two problems with a request class, it's a request for a Hostinger database, the errors are:

> "Cannot resolve method method 'super(int,
>   java.lang.String,com.android.volley.Response.Listener,null)'"
>   and the other error: "Method does not override method from its
>   superclass"

```
package com.example.nikochan.instaticket;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class CrearEventoRequest extends CrearEvento {
    private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = "http://instatickethome.xyz/Crea.php";
    private Map<String,String> params;

    public CrearEventoRequest (String nombreevento, String fecha, String descripcion, String hora, String genero, String edad, String duracion, String precio, Response.Listener<String> listener){

        super (Request.Method.POST,LOGIN_REQUEST_URL,listener,null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("nombreevento",nombreevento);
        params.put("fecha",fecha);
        params.put("descrpcion",descripcion);
        params.put("hora",hora);
        params.put("genero",genero);
        params.put("edad",edad + "");
        params.put("duracion",duracion);
        params.put("precio",precio + "");

        }
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

Comment: `CrearEvento` class does not have the cinstructor you are trying to call.

Answer (score 0):

First error says, super class doesn't have a constructor that matching your call.

Second error says, super class doesn't have getParams() method. You can't override it. Remove the @Override annotation.

> When overriding a method, you might want to use the @Override annotation that instructs the compiler that you intend to override a method in the superclass. If, for some reason, the compiler detects that the method does not exist in one of the superclasses, then it will generate an error.